# PostAsync() method is not working in dot-net core window service

Tags: c#, service, .net-core, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying the run the **console application as a window service** in dot-net core and able to create ,start ,stop and delete the service.
I am using **PostAsync()** method in application but the issue is that this method is working perfectly in console application but in window service most of the times **PostAsync()** never returned any response.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
string abc=\"firstparameter\":\"English\",\"secondParameter\":\"Hindi\",\"Marks\":\"Result \"}";
var response = await client.PostAsync("url", new StringContent(ab, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false))
```

and By this way

```
var response = client.PostAsync("url", content).Result;
var objResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Where does your `client` come from?

Comment: First of all, never use `.Result`. This also implies you are not calling this method correctly in the first place. Are you `await`ing all the way up the call chain?

Comment: Hi @Anduin 
It is an object of  HttpClient class.

Comment: Hi @DavidG
I am aware of that and I have also used await  but it didn't work for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use it.
In this example I have used HttpClientFactory to create a HttpClient.

```
var userApi = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("UserApi");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "systemuser/login");
request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await userApi.SendAsync(request);

if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<LoginResponse>();
    return Ok(body);
}
return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: we can not use the dot net core application exe directly in our  service. So I changed the  approach Just created the window service application with exe and then used this service exe  further in  my another service .It  solved my problem

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response but just in case this could help someone here is my answer.

`StringContent` is not a good option when doing Post. You may want to use `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "firstparameter", "firstparametervalue" },
    { "secondparameter", "secondparametervalue" }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUri, content);
```